# Gorilla glue removal

Tags: adhesive

In our RV trailer has wallboard wallpaper. I have splotches of and dried drips of gorilla glue. What can I do to remove with out ruining wallpaper ?

Comment: what is `wallboard wallpaper` ?

Comment: Gorilla glue is urethane. Looks for a solvent that dissolves it when cured.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Polyurethane glue, once cured, is almost impossible to remove except by mechanical methods. So, you could try a razor blade or fine sandpaper, but you're almost certainly going to have marks left by the removal.